# react native NativeModule. RNDeviceInfo is null Error and Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication()

Tags: android, react-native, npm

I have react native app, and now that didnt run app for me.
I run with that commend:
`npx expo start`
e
that the error:

- NativeModule. RNDeviceInfo is null. To fix this issue try these steps: For react-native < 0.59: Run 'react-native link react-native-device-Info.
- Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKlQ6.png)

i try to use `npm Ci` for that and same resulte

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/issues/1558

This is the response to your query. I hope it helps. Kindly do as @mikehardy suggests.